# How to create a heatmap that follows the route on a map using leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a geojson file which is the coordinates of a route. In a csv file I have data with utm_lat, utm_lng, pasengers. Using leaflet in R how can I then ceate a heatmap that folows the route only? Do I need other types of data files?

I get something similar to:
[enter link description here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi0.wp.com%2Fwww.supplychaindataanalytics.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F10%2Fburger-left-pizza-right-OSM.png%3Ffit%3D1250%252C437%26ssl%3D1&tbnid=UNuY4Lk9jur-7M&vet=12ahUKEwidopapksX-AhWWtyoKHQylBOYQMygAegUIARCyAQ..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.supplychaindataanalytics.com%2Fleaflet-heatmaps-in-r%2F&docid=I4hgRTTiq3fdWM&w=1250&h=437&q=r%20heatmap%20map%20leaflet&ved=2ahUKEwidopapksX-AhWWtyoKHQylBOYQMygAegUIARCyAQ)

But i want it to look like this:
[enter link description here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328037289/figure/fig8/AS:677476736966656@1538534449621/Heatmap-of-Speed-en-Route-Highway-or-Urban-Perimeter.ppm)

A part of my code in R shiny app:
heatway1 is filteret where the direction is filteret to way1, heatway2 is filteret to way2

```
  heatway1 <- data.frame(heatway1$utm_lng, heatway1$utm_lat, heatway1$passengers)
  colnames(heatway1) <- c("lng", "lat", "value")
  heatway2 <- data.frame(heatway2$utm_lng, heatway2$utm_lat, heatway2$passengers)
  colnames(heatway2) <- c("lng", "lat", "value")

map <- leaflet(filtered_data()) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = mean(filtered_data()$utm_lng), 
              lat = mean(filtered_data()$utm_lat), 
              zoom = 13)
    
    map <- map %>%
      addHeatmap(data = heatway1, intensity = ~value, blur = 20, max = 20, radius = 25, group = "way1")
    
    map <- map %>%
      addHeatmap(data = heatway2, intensity = ~value, blur = 20, max = 20, radius = 25, group = "way2")
    
    map <- map %>%
      addLegend(
        position = "bottomleft",
        pal = pal,
        values = ~passengers,
        title = "Passengers",
        opacity = 1
      )

    map <- map %>% addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("way1", "way2"), options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)) %>%
      addGeodesicPolylines(data = geojsonroutedata, color = "#03F", opacity = 0.5) %>%
      addResetMapButton() %>% addSearchOSM() %>% addScaleBar(position = "bottomleft") # %>% addFullscreenControl()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to

> I get something similar to: [your link 1](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi0.wp.com%2Fwww.supplychaindataanalytics.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F10%2Fburger-left-pizza-right-OSM.png%3Ffit%3D1250%252C437%26ssl%3D1&tbnid=UNuY4Lk9jur-7M&vet=12ahUKEwidopapksX-AhWWtyoKHQylBOYQMygAegUIARCyAQ..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.supplychaindataanalytics.com%2Fleaflet-heatmaps-in-r%2F&docid=I4hgRTTiq3fdWM&w=1250&h=437&q=r%20heatmap%20map%20leaflet&ved=2ahUKEwidopapksX-AhWWtyoKHQylBOYQMygAegUIARCyAQ)
> But i want it to look like this: [your link 2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328037289/figure/fig8/AS:677476736966656@1538534449621/Heatmap-of-Speed-en-Route-Highway-or-Urban-Perimeter.ppm)

and your description of data, it is probably usefull to snap the points corresponding to the route before making the heatmap. You can snap points to nearest line with maptools: https://maptools.r-forge.r-project.org/reference/snapPointsToLines.html

**Edit:**

You'll have to improve by considering both "ways" but the logic I was picturing is as follows

```
library(sf)
library(spData)
library(leaflet)

#### converting polygon dataset to lines for tiny example
nz_as_lines <- nz %>%
  st_cast(x = ., to = "MULTILINESTRING")

# plotting
plot(nz_as_lines$geom)
plot(nz_height$geometry, add=TRUE, col = 'blue')

#### snapping operation
nz_height_relocated <- maptools::snapPointsToLines(points = as(nz_height, Class = "Spatial"), 
                            lines = as(nz_as_lines, Class = "Spatial"), maxDist = 20000) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# difference:
plot(nz_height_relocated$geometry, add=TRUE, col = 'red')

# converting points as WGS84 for leaflet
nz_height_relocated <- nz_height_relocated %>%
  st_transform(x = ., crs = 4326)

map <- leaflet(nz_height_relocated) %>%
  addTiles()

map <- map %>%
  leaflet.extras::addHeatmap(data = nz_height_relocated, intensity = ~snap_dist, blur = 20, max = 20, radius = 25, group = "way1")

map
```

If you zoom in the center, the several initial points are well aligned with the border of the regions. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried to explain more with reproducible example